# Dual vector of sum of vectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am new to QM and have a question regarding bra-ket notation and dual vectors.

I have a vector $|\Psi\rangle = |a\rangle + k|b\rangle$, where $k$ is some complex number k = $x + iy$. I want to find the dual vector $\langle\Psi|$. I have some ideas about this but I'm not sure which (if any) is right.

$\langle\Psi|$ = ($|\Psi\rangle)^{\dagger}$ = $(|a\rangle + k|b\rangle)^{*}$ = $|a\rangle^{*} + k^{*}|b\rangle^{*}$ = $\langle a|^{*} + k^{*}\langle b|^{*}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your second equality indicates that you think $\dagger$ and $*$ are the same operation.

Comment: "langle", not <, and "rangle" for >. For example: $\langle \psi \rangle$ vs <$\psi$>.

Answer (score 1):

If we have an equation among kets such as
$$a|V\rangle=b|W\rangle+c|Z\rangle+\cdots$$

this implies another one among the corresponding bras:
$$\langle V|a^*=\langle W|b^*+\langle Z|c^*+\cdots$$

In your case $$|\Psi\rangle=|a\rangle+k|b\rangle$$
the corresponding relation in bras:

$$\langle \Psi|=\langle a|+\langle b|k^*$$

---

Note:  Given a ket $\alpha|V\rangle\equiv |\alpha V\rangle$ the corresponding bra is
$$\langle \alpha V|=\langle V|\alpha^*$$

In the same way, given a ket
$$\Omega|V\rangle=|\Omega V\rangle$$
the corresponding bra is
$$\langle\Omega V|=\langle V|\Omega^\dagger$$

where $\Omega $ is operator.

Comment: Traditionally one writes: $a^*\langle \psi|$ rather than $\langle \psi|a^*$

Comment: $\alpha|V\rangle\equiv |aV\rangle$ Why are you inconsistent about $a$ and $\alpha$?

Comment: @G.Smith Sorry! I edited it.

Comment: @JEB I followed R Shankar's  Quantum mechanics for my course and So it's the same as theirs.